# How to measure delivery rate on weekly basis in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have below-mentioned data in R.

```
ID    DateTime1            DateTime2            attribute  Type   Status   batch    delivery_date 
P-1   2021-02-01 10:15:20  2021-02-01 10:15:20  New        CCR1   Done     XA1      2021-02-01 12:15:20
P-2   2021-02-01 10:15:20  2021-02-02 15:45:28  New        CCR1   Hold     XA1      
P-3   2021-02-01 10:15:20  2021-02-01 10:15:20  Old        CDR1   Done     RR1      2021-02-01 12:15:20
P-4   2021-02-01 10:15:20  2021-02-01 10:15:20  Old        DYR1   Done     XY1      2021-02-01 12:15:20
P-5   2021-02-01 10:15:20  2021-02-01 19:45:52  New        CDR1   WIP      XA1
```

dput(head(df,10))

```
structure(list(ID = c("P-1", "P-2", 
"P-3", "P-4", "P-5", "P-6", 
"P-7", "P-8", "P-9", "P-10"
), DateTime1= c("2021-03-01 03:19:03.364", "2021-03-01 03:28:52.871", 
"2021-03-01 03:52:01.734", "2021-03-01 04:11:28.083", "2021-03-01 04:16:36.579", 
"2021-03-01 04:23:07.379", "2021-03-01 04:24:05.035", "2021-03-01 04:26:07.860", 
"2021-03-01 04:29:42.571", "2021-03-01 04:34:37.919"), DateTime2 = c("2021-03-01 05:03:02.510", 
"2021-03-01 06:15:28.954", "2021-03-02 06:28:19.316", "2021-03-04 13:25:45.871", 
"2021-03-02 12:27:07.154", "2021-03-01 05:01:58.497", "2021-03-01 05:12:54.269", 
"2021-03-03 07:39:05.244", "2021-03-01 05:03:49.996", "2021-03-01 06:01:16.509"
), attribute = c("New", "New", "New", "New", "New", 
"New", "New", "New", "New", "New"), TYPE = c("CCR1", 
" CCR1", " CCR1", " CCR1", " CCR1", 
" CCR1", " CDR1", " CDR1", " CCR1", 
" CCR1"), Status = c("Hold", "Done", 
"Done", "Done", "Done", 
"Hold", "Hold", "Done", 
"WIP", "Done"), Batch = c("XA1", 
"XA1", "XA1", "XA1", "XA1", "RR1", "RR1", "XA1", "XY1", "XA1"),
delivery_date = c(NA, "2021-03-01 06:15:29", 
"2021-03-01 03:52:03", "2021-03-01 04:11:29", "2021-03-01 04:16:38", 
NA, NA, "2021-03-01 04:26:09", NA, "2021-03-01 06:01:16")), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

I need to derive the time difference on hourly basis for each `Date` by using the above mentioned dataframe with following condition.

The condition is, `DateTime1` should be used to derive the base date (i.e 2021-02-01) and I need to consider the date difference only for those `ID` which has `Type` is equal to `CCR1` and Batch is equal to `XA1` on a weekly basis for that particular Month.

The logic is, If there is no `delivery_date` and `Status` is equal to Hold then take a difference of `DateTime2` - `DateTime1` (let's call it Diff1) and If `delivery_date` is available then take difference of `delivery_date` - `DateTime1` (let's call it Diff2) and If `delivery_date` is not available but `Status` is other than Hold then consider it in `Other` and take difference of system date time - `DateTime1` (let's call it Diff3). The difference should be in Days and Hours, For example if the average hours is <24 then hours else in Days.

Where, we can create a bucket on hourly basis based on the `Diff` values, starting from <1 hours with every 1 hours difference and last one as 9+ hours. Also, take a average in Total column for `Diff1`, `Diff2` and `Diff3`

Required Output Format:

```
Month       Count   Count_1   Per_1  Diff1   Count_2  Per_2   Diff2  Count_3  Per_3    Diff3
Feb-21 (W1) 3       1         33.33% 5.5h    1        33.33%  2h     1        33.33%   32 Days
Feb-21 (W2) 0       0         0.00%  0       0        0.00%   0      0        0.00%    0
Feb-21 (W3) 0       0         0.00%  0       0        0.00%   0      0        0.00%    0
Feb-21 (W4) 0       0         0.00%  0       0        0.00%   0      0        0.00%    0
Total       3       1         33.33% 5.5h    1        33.33%  2h     1        33.33%   32 Days
```

Comment: @RonakShah- Updated the dput of my df.

Comment: What is your question, exactly? What have you tried? I would approach this by using dplyr::mutate with dplyr::case_when to input your conditionals for each and set the default to 0 instead of NA, which will then allow you to summarize into your format. However, as I said, the question isn't clear and you'd be better off chunking off this "question" into components that are more easily addressable (and likely are already answered).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution - For the time difference I leave it all to hours as I couldn't figure out way to have hour / days diffference in one column. Once you have the data you can print them out or create a dummy variables separately but for columns consistently time-difference - it has to be either in hours or days not mix.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(tidyr)

df %>% mutate(
  # define the time system as logic provided
  time_system = case_when(
    Status == "Hold" ~ "Diff_1",
    !is.na(delivery_date) ~ "Diff_2",
    TRUE ~ "Diff_3" ),
  # Base on the time system calculate the time difference according to the rule
  calcuclate_diff = case_when(
    time_system == "Diff_1" ~ difftime(DateTime2, DateTime1, units = "hours"),
    time_system == "Diff_2" ~ difftime(delivery_date, DateTime1, units = "hours"),
    time_system == "Diff_3" ~ difftime(Sys.time(), DateTime1, units = "hours")
  ),
  # create the formating date for Month & Week
  month = format(as.Date(DateTime1), "%b-%y"),
  week = week(DateTime1) - week(floor_date(as.Date(DateTime1), unit = "months")) + 1,
  format_date = paste0(month, " (W", week, ")")) %>%
  # calculate the variables that needed grouped by month-week
  group_by(format_date, time_system) %>%
  summarize(Count = n(),
    Average = mean(calcuclate_diff),
    .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(format_date) %>%
  mutate(Total_count = sum(Count),
    Per = Count / sum(Count)) %>%
  # pivot the data wide to have the final expecting format
  pivot_wider(names_from = time_system, values_from = c(Count, Average, Per),
    names_sort = FALSE, names_glue = "{.value}_{time_system}")
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 1 x 11
# Groups:   format_date [1]
  format_date Total_count Count_Diff_1 Count_Diff_2 Count_Diff_3 Average_Diff_1 Average_Diff_2  Average_Diff_3 Per_Diff_1 Per_Diff_2 Per_Diff_3
  <chr>             <int>        <int>        <int>        <int> <drtn>         <drtn>          <drtn>              <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 Mar-21 (W1)          10            3            6            1 1.064768 hours 0.7036553 hours 155.1412 hours        0.3        0.6        0.1
```

Comment: It looks like this answer represents substantial effort toward answering your (very involved) question, and generated output that appears to me consistent with your request, though with slightly different variable names (which is trivial to change). Your feedback would be more constructive and considerate of others' efforts on your behalf if you described specifically what is not working.

Comment: @JonSpring: I am not getting `Count` column and all `Aveerage_Diff_x` columns are coming `NA`. I'm trying to figure out the exact issue to get the desired output.

Comment: I added the total count column though the Average may get NA depend on the input so if you have provide a broader range of sample data where the NA can be introduce in Average (I guess with N `DateTime2`) then I can confirm it by just use `na.rm` in `mean` calculation